# Unable to get string response message from server

Tags: javascript, api, server, client, response

Unable to get data responses from server on my client application. Sending data from server and it is also showing in my network tab responses but I am not be able to get it on my client application

## Server code:

```
res.status(400).send("cannot delete company until you have groups attached, either delete all or assign all those groups to some other company first")
```

## Client code:

```
async function deleteApi() {
            const responseDelete = await fetch(`https://baseUrl.com/company/${id}`, {
                method: 'DELETE',
            });
            const responseDeleteJson = await responseDelete.json()
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log("err: ", err);
                })
            // console.log("Delete response", responseDeleteJson);
        }
        deleteApi()
```

Comment: is "baseUrl.com" the actual url you're trying to access?

Comment: No, I just replace the actual URL.

Comment: So should it be `https://${actualUrl}/company/${id}` or have you just written it as a string so as not to share the details on the stackoverflow question?

Comment: Yes, I just replace the actual URL with this dummy URL, Just to hide my server URL.